# Nadir sensor for a spacecraft attempting to land

Tags: spacecraft, landing, sensors

Is it possible theoretically for a sensor to detect Nadir? This could actually be of extreme value as generally spacecraft attempting to land need to maintain certain heading w.r.t Nadir as a function of altitude and down range.

Closest I can think of is [gravity gradient sensors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_gradiometry). The idea here would be to detect gravity direction which should be for all intent and purposes aligned to Nadir(or not?). Also, I have an intuition that these gravity gradient sensors will also work even if the thrusters are firing. Am I correct? Is there any better way to detect Nadir directly by sensor/sensors?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, nadir detection is possible.

The best technique depends on how high you are and how accurate you need to be.

If you have enough altitude to see the entire horizon-to-horizon disc of the planet, a simple approach is to capture an image of it and compute the center.

Using magnetometers is another approach.

A star tracker could also work, although accuracy would depend on knowing the time and your location.

Closer to the ground, I would probably use LIDAR. Scan the area below, looking for the closest point, which would be nadir.

A production version of nadir-sensing would almost certainly involve several different instruments, with readings combined in an attitude measurement control system. Different instruments may work better at different altitudes; the control system would know this, and change usage or weights as the mission progresses.

Comment: Horizon is a good idea and works anywhere on Earth as long as you are very hight, but when you get closer to the ground (as in the landing attempt mentioned in the question) mountains, landmarks, buildings, even trees will cause a problem. The other two would require you *know* roughly where you are landing (latitude, longitude) and they have other problems. Even a 3D vector magnetometer + vector magnetic map of the Earth + lat/lon leaves 1 axis of ambiguity, you can spin one axis the field line and since the other two would read zero, they'd never know it.

Comment: Star tracking is useless if there is any weather or city lights or if it's a daytime landing, and a shaking, maneuvering, landing rocket might be a real challenge from which to image stars and measure their positions.

Comment: star trackers work in the daytime @uhoh, and have been able to do since since at least 1958

Comment: As I said, it depends on how high you are. If you're in near space, above the clouds, then a star tracker works fine, even in day and in the presence of city lights (I've done that), unless the sun is in the FOV. Vibration, clouds and heat would be a problem as you get lower, though.

Comment: Close to the ground requires a different approach. Offhand, I'd say gyros should work well, synced while still well above the clouds. Haven't done it myself, though.

Comment: For the magnetometer approach, here's a link to a paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7500665

Comment: OP specifies a landing and does not specify only landing on airless worlds; not too many of those in 1958 @JCRM There are plenty of adcs-tagged Q&A's here *but this one is about a nadir sensor for landing*. I'm also not sure how the optics is going to perform after being exposed to atmospheric reentry.

Comment: How does star tracker help ? It only tells attitude w.r.t inertial frame, Nadir is w.r.t local frame !

Comment: @uhoh, what on earth have airless worlds got to do with it? As for reentry the opticas would tend to be on the leeward side, but failing that an outer layer of quartz could be popped off a la soyuz.

Comment: @Prakhar the answer explains it, re-read last sentence.

Comment: @JCRM landing on body w/ atmosphere during the day, normal ones can't see stars. Q is about landing.

Comment: but by 1958, @uhoh, atmospheric vehicles were flying with star trackers that could see stars during the day. It would be pretty pointless to have mentioned it otherwise.

Comment: @RickNZ that paper isn't about landing, it's a very slow-response system producing only a nominal alignment to the nadir over an extended period of time, *that only works for a satellite in a stable orbit*. The question is about landing a rocket, where things happen very quickly.

Comment: @uhoh the idea is that you first determine nadir while the rocket is still in space, then use an attitude measurement control system to propagate that model as you descend. If you want or need data close to the surface, then use a LIDAR. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Prakhar if you know the time and your XYZ position, you can calculate the inertial direction that corresponds to nadir in the local frame.

Comment: Using LIDAR close to the ground to detect the closest point requires a nearly flat surface. You don't want to get the next mountain top.

Comment: @RickNZ If I know my XYZ exactly then sure. But what are you missing is the models used to propagate the XYZ required the inertial attitude knowledge at first place !  And star sensor are useless because during firing the rates are large enough for SS to not work perfectly. Generally all landers have one SS update before initiating landing trajectory. The errors in XYZ is exactly why I was thinking of Nadir sensor at first place !